# python FOR loop 2 consecutive loops in one function only 1st loop runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, for-loop

I have two FOR loops that can run fine individually. When i try to run them together in the same function only the first loop is run.

My code looks like this:

```
def loop_code():
        for x in range(10):
            x -= 1 
            print(x)
        for y in range(10):
            y += 1 
            print(y)

loop_code()
```

output:

```
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I need to output this instead:

```
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code seems to be working as it should.
Check [this](https://repl.it/@MikhailPiervii/InsecureYoungCryptocurrency#main.py)
There might be a problem not connected to your code directly. Provide more info about your system, IDE and/or how you run your code

Comment: Code is working fine! What's the problem?

Comment: check out the definiton of range() function. a change as simple as ````range(12)```` would do. (think about it, you want 12 instances!)

Answer (score 0):

That is not an elegant way to do the things. Modifying your index variable while in a for loop breaks the interest of said for loop.
If you want you loop to go from -1 to 8 use:

```
for index in range(-1,9)
```

Then if you want your second for loop to have its index go from 1 to 10 use:

```
for other_index in range(1,11)
```

Your question could use some clarification. I'm helping you on getting the output you want but there might be some [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) going on here. Is there a particular reason you wanted to modify your index in the for-loop?

Comment: This is general non specific question on FOR loops within functions in python. I have more complex code that needs two definite loops to be performed by calling a function. Do you know of a better method to performing this action?

Answer (score 0):

check out the definiton of range() function. a change as simple as `range(12)` would do. (think about it, you want 12 itarations!)